# Negative of system of equations giving different answer

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I encountered something strange and it's probably just a silly error, but I need some help in understanding what's going on.

Consider the first set of nonlinear equations below and the computed solution.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

m = 0.8
n = 0.5

def equations1(p1):
    x1, y1 = p1
    return (m*x1+n*y1+1,y1-x1**2-1)

x1, y1 = fsolve(equations1, (0.5,0.5))
print equations1((x1,y1)) 

(0.9441394305358858, -0.47173248837117643)
```

Now, multiply the equations by negative 1 and solve (NOTE: this should be the same set of equations since solve is solving equations of the form f(x)=0).

```
def equations2(p2):
    x2, y2 = p2
    return (-1*(m*x2+n*y2+1),-1*(y2-x2**2-1))

x2, y2 = fsolve(equations2, (0.5,0.5))
print equations2((x2,y2))

(-0.9441394305358858, 0.47173248837117643)
```

Why are the solutions negated as well?

Comment: Well, `equations2` returns the negation, and you are directly printing the result of `equations2`, right? Print `x2` and `y2`; they should be the same.

Comment: Hmm, but I thought equations1 represents the system mx1 + ny1+1 = 0, y1-x1^2-1=0, and equations2 represents the system -(mx1 + ny1+1) = 0, -(y1-x1^2-1)=0 which mathematicall is the same set. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, but you *print* the negation. The solutions are the same. Check this out: https://repl.it/repls/KnottyChartreuseFormats `(x1, y1) == (x2, y2)`

Comment: Try printing `x2` and `y2`

Comment: I see! Thank you!